# Array modifier with varying scaling/scale to curve

Tags: modifiers

I am looking for a simpler way to create what I have manually done below.
[image]

I have a curve in orange and a mesh (the grey sphere) centered at the origin.  I want to array this mesh.  The center of each sphere should be on the x axis, and the size should be scaled so it touches the curve.  It is important to me that each object in the array is exactly a scaling of the original.

I feel like I want to apply a curve modifier to the array'd spheres, but I need to lock the center and allow them to scale.

As an example application: if we want to make a simple ladder we could use an array modifier to make each step.  What would we do if we had a funky ladder where each step had a different length?

Comment: press ctrl+A rotation & scale

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  All of my objects have their rotation and scale set to (0,0,0) and (1,1,1).

Comment: Did you try to use an empty for the Array Modifier as an Offset Object? Scaling the empty influences the Size of each arrayed Object

Comment: The problem is that if you do that, each offset is fixed.  I need the offset to vary, depending on the curve.

Comment: Could not figure out a smart way to do this either, closest thing I got is using curve radius, but it will distort the spheres